# Video converter for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, video, media-converter

I am looking for a software for Linux which could do the following:

- Convert video from one file type to another
- Split/join video files
- Compress video files to reduce the size
- Has a GUI
- Free
- Low learning curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on Linux / Mac OS X / Windows
- GUI
- Allows to [split](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:cutting#autosplit) and join video files
- Can encode a video
- Pretty easy to use

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, especially Debian type (Ubuntu, Mint, etc )  you might look at WinFF for converting files "except .mkv".  For .mkv , Transmageddon works well and is available from the Repository. Transmageddon doesn't do batch files.  Just single files.  WinFF does batch files, but not for .mkv.   AVIDemux is an alternative, but a bit more complicated.  In general usage, WinFF and Transmageddon seem to do what I need.

Links: [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) & 
[Transmageddon](http://www.linuxrising.org/)

Answer (score 1):

On any OS like Win, Linux or Mac is Handbrake a very good Solution. The Overview is compact. Not thousand of pins to make manually changes - for all kinds of mobile devices and desktop solutions are predefined configurations available. (Build-in Device Presets)
Support the most common Multimedia Files include Blu-ray or DVD.
Easy to use. Open Source.
￼

Answer (score 0):

[KDENlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) and [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org/) both meet your requirements.